# What does double vertical lines $\|$ mean in number theory?

Tags: number-theory, notation

I'm reading the 2002 paper [P is in PRIMES](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v160-n2-p12.pdf) and I stumbled upon this symbol $\|$ in the chapter 2:

> Suppose $n$ is composite. Consider a prime $q$ that is a factor of $n$ and
>   let **$q^k\ ||\ n$**. Then $q^k$ does not divide $n \choose q$ and is coprime to $a^{n−q}$ and hence the coefficient of $X^q$ is not zero $(\mod n\ )$. Thus $((X + a)^n − (X^n + a))$ is not identically zero over $Z^n$.

I am very new to number theory and it is not mentioned anywhere in the paper what $\|$ denotes. I tried looking it up in the [Wikipedia List of mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) but I couldn't find anything.

Does anyone know what $\|$ means in this context?

Comment: || is right below | (and $\not\mid$) in the Wikipedia list; you can get to it by searching the page for "exact divisibility" (or just "divisibility").

Comment: @BarryCipra Ooh cool! Thanks! I tried searching for the ascii `||` but couldn't find it. Looks it it uses some utf-8 symbols for the that (namely `∣∣`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means that $q^k$ fully divides $n,$ that is, $q^k$ divides $n$ but $q^{k+1}\nmid n.$

Comment: Thanks. But what does $\nmid$ mean? Not dividable? But wouldn't that be true iff $q$ is not dividable by $n$.

Comment: Yes, $a\nmid b$ means that $b$ is not divisible by $a.$

Comment: Thank you! So just for confirmation, $$a^n \| b \Rightarrow a^n = b (\ mod\ 0\ )$$  or $$(a^n \| b \Rightarrow a^n = b (\ mod\ 0\ )) \land \neg (a = b (\ mod\ 0\ ))$$? From what you said it sounded like the later. But it feels like you are referring to the former.

Comment: Oops I meant to but $a^n$ inside mod and leave 0 outside. I got it now, thank you so much!

Comment: Note: $a^n \vert\vert b$ is defined only when $a$ is prime.

Comment: And my parenthesis was wrong after the 6th edit .. oops.

Comment: @GEdgar Ooh. So more formally we have  $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall b \in \mathbb{Z},  \forall a \in \text{PRIMES} \  a^n \| b $$ ?