# Riemann's prime counting function $J(x)$ and the convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(\zeta(n))}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, solution-verification

**Introduction**

There is some disagreement on what notation to use for the weighted prime function, but I'm gonna use the notation $J(x)$ for it ($f(x)$ is also used a lot). The function is defined as follows (according [WolframMathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannPrimeCountingFunction.html)):
$$J(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\log_2(x)}\frac{\pi(x^{\frac{1}{n}})}{n}$$ 
Here $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function. Note that we put the end to the series at $\log_2(x)$ because after that the terms become $0$. Intuitively, the function is essentially "counting prime powers $p^n$ with a weight of $\frac{1}{n}$". So when $x$ is a prime the function "jumps" by $1$, when $x$ is a square of a prime it jumps by $\frac{1}{2}$, when $x$ is a cube of a prime it jumps by $\frac{1}{3}$ and so on.

This seemingly useless function satisfies the following amazing relationship:
$$\displaystyle \ln \zeta (n)=n\int _{0}^{\infty }J(x)x^{-n-1}\,\mathrm {d} x$$

Now I'm interested in all kinds of series involving $\zeta(n)$ so this got me thinking; I have [just been discussing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3626545/what-does-sum-n-2-infty-ln-zetan-converge-to) a similar infinite series and now I thought of the following one:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(\zeta(n))}{n}$$

You probably recognize the inside of the sum; it's just the relationship above, but we've divided by $n$. So we can rewrite this as:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(\zeta(n))}{n} =\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \int _{0}^{\infty }J(x)x^{-n-1}\,\mathrm {d} x$$

Now I'm going to simplify this:

\begin{align} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(\zeta(n))}{n} &= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \int _{0}^{\infty }J(x)x^{-n-1}\,\mathrm {d} x \\\\ & = \int _{0}^{\infty}(\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} J(x)x^{-n-1})\,\mathrm {d} x \\\\ & = \int _{0}^{\infty}J(x)(\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{n+1}})\,\mathrm {d} x \end{align}

According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20n%3D2%20to%20infinity%20of%201%2F%28x%5E%28n%2B1%29%29) the series can be simplified as follows:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{(x-1)x^2}$$

And thus, we arrive at the final result that:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(\zeta(n))}{n} = \int _{0}^{\infty}\frac{J(x)}{(x-1)x^2}\,\mathrm {d} x$$

**Question**

Is this correct? I feel like I did some mistake when I switched the sum and integral. Also note that the following
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{(x-1)x^2}$$
only converges for $|x| > 1$ which probably makes my derivation false. Any ideas on whether it is true what I have done or not?

Comment: Isn't $J(x)=0$ for $0<x<2$?

Comment: @Gary Yes, that's true cause there is no prime in that interval.

Comment: @Gary I'm sorry if I don't realize it but does that make my derivation false or?

Comment: The integrand is positive, whence you can interchange th order of summation and integration. Because of my comment above, in reality, you integrate from $x=2$. However, for $x>2$, the series converges to $1/((x-1)x^2)$. Thus, your formula must be correct.

Comment: @Gary Thank you, now I understand! I think this answers my question so you can make an answer if you want, but that's your choice. Thanks, once again.

Comment: @Gary Btw do you have any idea of how I could numerically check this? WolframAlpha seems to be loading for so long and I think it doesn't have the function $J(x)$

Comment: You may try to us the representation above of $J(x)$ in terms of the prime counting function.